# grep regex port range from netstat

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression, numeric-data

In my netstat output, I want to extract port range between `32000-64000`. I have tried `egrep "^[3,4,5,6]"` but I need to start from `32000`.  Should I use `awk` or some kind of script?

```
Linux# netstat -nau
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:55238      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:55240      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:31242      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:55244      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:32246      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:55248      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:12250      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:19252      0.0.0.0:*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
netstat -nau | awk -F'[[:space:]]+|:' 'NR>2 && $5>=32000 && $5<=64000'
```

The output in your case would be as:

```
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:55238      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:55240      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:55244      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:32246      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.0.0.20:55248      0.0.0.0:*
```

---

- `-F'[[:space:]]+|:'` - field separator
- `NR>2 && $5>=32000 && $5<=64000` - checks if port number is in the needed range

---

Alternative ***egrep*** solution:

```
netstat -nau | egrep ':(3[2-9]|[45][0-9])[0-9]{3}|6[0-3][0-9]{3}|64000'
```

- `(3[2-9]|[45][0-9])[0-9]{3}` - will cover numbers from `32000` to `59999`
- `6[0-3][0-9]{3}|64000` - will cover numbers from `60000` to `64000`

Comment: you godamn!!! right...so cool

Comment: @Satish, welcome! I also added additional `egrep` approach (but I would use `awk`)

Answer (score 3):

As `netstat` is deprecated, why not try its superior successor, `ss`.

```
ss -nau '( sport >= 32000 and sport <= 64000 )'
```